# Can I repeat method using CompletableFuture until value is true

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, completable-future

I have a Java method that gets a value from a database table cell.
Let's name it `jdbcTemplate.queryForObject()`

I want to run this method once per 2 minutes until the value of the cell becomes `true`.

Is it possible to achieve this using CompletableFuture?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

1. A `CompletableFuture` is a mechanism for delivering a result from one thread to another.  It doesn't have any functionality for computing things or repeating things.
2. A `CompletableFuture` returns one value only.  Once it has been "completed", the value cannot be changed.  You can call `complete` multiple times with different values, but they will be ignored according to the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#complete(T)).

Of course, you could write some code that repeatedly queries the database, and only calls `complete(...)` when the database cell becomes true.  For example:

```
// Do this twice a minute until it succeeds.
if (jdbcTemplate.queryForObject()) {
    future.complete(Boolean.TRUE);
    // stop repeating ...
}
```

The idea is to call `complete` just once to deliver a result ... and then terminate the loop or whatever that is repeating the query.

But that's not *using* `CompletableFuture` to do the repeated queries.

Note: you should also consider cases such as the query taking too long, or failing with an exception.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this working example:

```
    CompletableFuture<Object> future = new CompletableFuture<>();


    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Object o = "jdbcTemplate.queryForObject()";
                if (o != null) {
                    future.complete(o);
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                future.completeExceptionally(ex);
            }
        }
    }, 0, 1000*2*60);
    System.out.println("checking database periodically ran");
    future.thenAccept(o -> {
        System.out.println(o);
        timer.cancel();
    }).join();
```